# Tensorflow Multiple Input Loss Function

Tags: function, tensorflow, loss

I am trying to implement a CNN in Tensorflow (quite similar architecture to VGG), which then splits into two branches after the first fully connected layer. It follows this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.01697

Each of the two branches of the network outputs a set of 32 numbers. I want to write a joint loss function, which will take 3 inputs:

1. The predictions of branch 1 (y)
2. The predictions of branch 2 (alpha)
3. The labels Y (ground truth) (q)

and calculate a weighted loss, as in the image below:

[Loss function definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aghfl.png)

```
q_hat = tf.divide(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(alpha, y),0), tf.reduce_sum(alpha,0))
loss  = tf.abs(tf.subtract(q_hat, q))
```

I understand the fact that I need to use the tf functions in order to implement this loss function. Having implemented the above function, the network is training, but once trained, it is not outputting the expected results.

Has anyone ever tried combining outputs of two branches of a network in one joint loss function? Is this something TensorFlow supports? Maybe I am making a mistake somewhere here? Any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you would like me to add any further details.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not outputting the expected results"?

Comment: Once trained on the same dataset and using the same methodology as the paper, my results are different. Specifically, the weighting branch does not learn much as it outputs zeros. I'd love to see some examples of a similar, 2-branch loss function written in TF. I've had some better results today after tweaking the cost function last night. Will keep this updated.

Answer (score 1):

From TensorFlow perspective, there is absolutely no difference between a "regular" CNN graph and a "branched" graph. For TensorFlow, it is just a graph that needs to be executed. So, TensorFlow certainly supports this. "Combining two branches into joint loss" is also nothing special. In fact, it is "good" that loss depends on both branches. It means that when you ask TensorFlow to compute loss, it will have to do the forward pass through both branches, which is what you want.

One thing I noticed is that your code for loss is different than the image. Your code appears to do this https://ibb.co/kbEH95